# Angular 2 Client for SignalR 3 .Net Core Failure on Negotiate

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, signalr

I'm working with a .Net Core application and attempting to get signalr to communicate between Angular 2 client and .Net backend.
My $.connection.url = "/signalr".

I have logging enabled:

SignalR: Client subscribed to hub 'postshub'.
SignalR: Negotiating with '/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22postshub%22%7D%5D'.
Error on init: Error: Error during negotiation request.
Error: Error during negotiation request.(…)
SignalR: Stopping connection.

My .Net is using SignalR.Server 0.2.0
My Angular 2 is using jquery.signalr-2.2.1.min.js

I can't find how to get better error statements, or any ideas on why I might be having a problem through searches.  So part of me is wondering if my signalR versions don't work well together.

I'll take any thoughts as to why it's not doing it, or how to get better feedback so that I can debug further myself.

Thanks

Comment: See what's happening on the server side and also what is the HTTP response (especially the status code). You can just send the negotiate request directly using the browser to make it easy.

Comment: Figured out it's a cross port issue.  My angular 2 side is one part, my server is another and the negotiation is trying to be called through the angular2 side when it needs to be the .net.  I put in the line $.connection.hub.url = "localhost:51137/signalr" to try to switch it but it's not coming through.

Comment: @bmac Im trying to get SignalR setup on asp.net core too, do you mind posting your project.json?